# How to save tableview data when moving from one view controller to another?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview

How to save data in tableview when moving from one View Controller to another

I'm trying to have the cells stay when I exit out of the app or move from view controller to view controller I've tried using multiple solutions on stack and I've tried the viewDidAppear to keep the cell data to stay in the CartVC but still no luck

SideNote: the cells in my CartVC are populated from another View Controller, when an item is selected in the view controller it is passed into the CartVC to populate the cells, every time I move from one VC to another (or close out the app) the data in the CartVC goes away how would I be able to have the data save in the CartVC

```
class CartViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    var selectedProduct: Items!

    var cart: [Cart] = []
    var groupedCartItems: [String: [Cart]] = [:]
    var brands: [String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var cartTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.        

        groupedCartItems = Dictionary(grouping: cart, by: {$0.cart.dispensaryName})
        dispensarySectionTitle = groupedCartItems.map{$0.key}.sorted()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        masterCartTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return brands.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let brand = brands[section]
        return groupedCartItems[brand]!.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cartCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartCell") as! CartCell        
        let brand = brands[indexPath.section]
        let itemsToDisplay = groupedCartItems[brands]![indexPath.row]
        cartCell.configure(withCartItems: itemsToDisplay.cart)

        return cartCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cartHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartHeader") as! CartHeader       
        let headerTitle = brands[section]
        cartHeader.brandName.text = "Store: \(headerTitle)"

        return cartHeader
    }      
}
```

Comment: For that, you need to save data in local databases like Coredata, Sqlite. If data is not that much heavy then you can save it in User default also.

Comment: im using cloud firestore as my database,  @swapnil pate how would I use User default to store for the time being

Comment: You can save an array of data into User default for the time being.

Comment: Im kind of confused on how to use user defaults since im not really use to using them in my code, what would be the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to save the data you can use user defaults

save it in local

```
let Defaults = UserDefaults.standard
Defaults.set(Yourvalue, forKey: "yourkey")
Defaults.synchronize()
```

Access it with

```
let yourvalueuset  =  UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "yourkey")
```

Comment: where would I put this if I was to save it to my "local"? the AppDelegate, the cartVC

Comment: I tried putting it in my viewDidLoad it didn't save anything, I put it in my cellFOrRowAt no luck either where would I put this to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Save your array as below:

```
let yourArray : [Any] = [] //Change your array type according to your requirement
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(yourArray, forKey: "your_key")
```

And get your array as below:

```
UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "your_key") //Get your array type according to you've saved before
```

Comment: I just tried running this, and it didn't save anything in the cart when I placed it in the viewDidLoad, and when I put this in the CellForAt it crashed the simulator and jumped to the app delegate